# How to config data header axios.pos using data from axios.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios, http-method

The first `axios.get` is getting data from local server and then pass into `axios.post` into 3rd party server.

If i pass '**data**' (hardcoded) into `axios.post`, 3rd party server send back response as `success operation`, but if i use '**data1**'  from `axios.get`, they send back respond that `something error/not valid` in my data, which actually, hardcoded '**data**' = '**data1**' as a result `axios.get`.

Where is something wrong in my code?

```
const catalog = async (req, res) => {

const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3500/catalog/SM-P6010ZKEXSE')
const data1 = JSON.stringify(result.data)

const data = 
{"Catalogues":[{"siteCode":"","modelCode":"SM-P6010ZKEXSE","modelDesc":"Tablet SM-601 BLACK XSE  E2014","datelist":[{"price":7450000,"status":"A","startDate":"20230509100316","endDate":"20240508100316"}]}]}

const header = {
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer xyz",  
    }
    } 

try {
    const result = await axios
        .post('https://external-server/catalog', data , header)
    
    {
        console.log('Update catalog success')
        console.log('status : ' + result.status)
        console.log(result.data)
        res.json(result.data)
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to update catalog')
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the above statement that you are using `JSON.stringify`. This will convert your object to string and your data variable is of type object change its type.

First, see your response and check if it is an object, then pass directly response data, which is an object in most cases. If it is not, then convert it to the appropriate type as your post request accepts.

if your response is already object, then change

```
const data1 = JSON.stringify(result.data)
```

to

```
const data1 = result.data
```

Comment: yes it's work, finally

Comment: @Dale , what do you mean about?